# Rigged Object does not effect the floor in physics simulation Rigid Body

Tags: armature, physics, rigid-body-simulation

[image: frame 1]

[image: frame 50]

[image: Rigid Body Settings Skeleton]

[image: Rigid Body Floor Settings]

Here you can see my scene. The skeleton is rigged with an armature. on the left side i created a spehere to demonstrate that the simulation is working. When i animated the skeleton i choose mesh colision and deform. When i play the simulation the skeleton mesh does not effect the floor as it should. I think this is beacause of the pivot point if the seperate objects. The Pivot Point is under the skeletton for all objects.

Maybe there is an easier way of doing this simulation.
Thanks for your help

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: Hello, @manu000, you haven't told us what the result of 'this simulation'  should be. So: 'as it should' has no meaning for those of us who are not telepathic :) . Please edit to clarify this post, with a plain description and/or illustration of the result you want to achieve.